# Perl CGI script displayed as plain text

Tags: apache, perl, centos, cgi

I moved all my websites to another server and all is working good but, my perl scripts are not running, are displayed as plain text.

A perl script must be running on this [URL](http://www.prestoprint.ca/cgi-bin/filechucker.cgi).

My vhost for that website is the following:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
 ServerName prestoprint.ca
 ServerAlias  www.prestoprint.ca
 ServerAdmin zadmin@localhost
 DocumentRoot "/path/prestoprint_ca"
 ErrorLog "/path/prestoprint_ca/error/error.log"

 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /path/prestoprint_ca/cgi-bin/

 <Directory "/path/prestoprint_ca">
     Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
 </Directory>

 <Directory "/path/prestoprint_ca/cgi-bin">
     Options +ExecCGI
     SetHandler cgi-script
 </Directory>
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3 .php
 DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.asp index.aspx index.jsp index.jspa index.shtml index.shtm filechucker.cgi
</virtualhost>
```

Really need help :(

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message the URL prints is:
You must either install the Digest::SHA1 Perl module, or else add the following to your prefs file:

$PREF{use_md5_for_hashes} = 'yes';

So you'll have to install Digest::SHA1 module through CPAN or distro's repo.

Comment: How can I install Digest::SHA1 on centos?

Comment: As root try ... `yum install perl-Digest-SHA1` ... assuming you're using System perl.